while I run the command npm run build then error is comming as CI= react scripts build, where CI is not recgonized by internal and external command
For my react project I am tryin to build the project by running the command npm run build then an error is encountered showing:

my-app@0.1.0 build
CI= react-scripts build
'CI' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Then I have changed the "build": "CI= react-scripts build" to "build": "react-scripts build", then another error is comming as:
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
at module.exports (C:\Users\ronig\OneDrive\Desktop\react course\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\ronig\OneDrive\Desktop\react course\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at C:\Users\ronig\OneDrive\Desktop\react course\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
at C:\Users\ronig\OneDrive\Desktop\react course\my-app\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
at C:\Users\ronig\OneDrive\Desktop\react course\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at C:\Users\ronig\OneDrive\Desktop\react course\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
at context.callback (C:\Users\ronig\OneDrive\Desktop\react course\my-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js    at C:\Users\ronig\OneDrive\Desktop\react course\my-app\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
Node.js v20.11.1

Does this answer your question? npm ERR! reminder@0.1.0 build: `CI= react-scripts build`
